# Retrieve DataRow after get sql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I`m new in VB.net and i need to create common function to retrieve data row. I tried this way. But this is not successful.

```
Function GetRecord(ByVal sql As String) As DataRow
        Dim conn As MySqlConnection = connect()
        Dim objDataSet As New DataSet
        Dim dt As DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow
        Try
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = sql
            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds, "T")
            dt = ds.Tables("T")
            dr = dt.Rows.Item(0)
        Catch e As Exception
            Throw e
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try
        GetRecord = dr
    End Function
```

remark: Connect() function returns mysql connection object

Comment: What error is being thrown? Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what are you trying to do but change your code to be like

```
    da.Fill(dt, "T")
    Catch e As Exception
        Throw e
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
    GetRecord = dt.Rows.Item(0)
```

Comment: This is wrong because it is still possible that `dt.Row.Items(0)` can throw an error and it would be uncaught with this implementation.